# Как открыть url в браузере по умолчанию при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу приложение с использованием JavaFX. Будет кнопка, при нажатии на которую, должен открыться браузер по умолчанию и начать загружать нужную страницу. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class SomeClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Open some site");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            getHostServices().showDocument("http://www.somesite.com");
        });


        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```